# Owncloud javascript Content Security Policy issue

Tags: javascript, security, content-security-policy, owncloud

I am developing an owncloud application.
When I try to add a `<script src="link to outer address"></script>` on template page, it tells me about Content Security Policy issue. Alternatively if I download the src file(I mean this file `<script src="file">`) into my project and the code of that file contains ajax queries to outer address, it tells me the following:

Refused to connect to 'url' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "connect-src 'self' url*

When I try the following on a simple project it works just fine.
I wonder is there an owncloud setting that blocks ajax calls 
to outer sources or just puts restrictions on javascript files. 
I tried to add meta tags it didn't help.

Thanks much in advance for any help

Answer (score -1):

It's documented here how to configure the security police. https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/12/developer_manual/app/controllers.html  Please also use Nextcloud instead of Owncloud because it is more actively developed and fully open source. Also more secure. 
Hope this helps.